# configuration issue of Firebase with Android Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an Android Project in which I have to use a database to store information. I have to create tables in it so that the clients use the application with the fresh data which is there in the Firebase.I have created an account in Firebase and wrote all the things which needed to be there in gradle file.

Build.gradel file(Project file)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

     packagingOptions{
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

        }

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.hsports.bandpop"
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 23
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

        }

        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I am clicking on the sync button to sync then it's giving me this error.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/I324671/AndroidStudioProjects/BandPop/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/I324671/AndroidStudioProjects/BandPop/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: make sure that your `Google Repository` is upto date with ver 36.

Comment: how to create this Google Repository and make it upto date with ver 36?

Comment: https://youtu.be/cNPCgJW8c-E?t=1m18s  But make sure your tools are more up to date than the ones in this video, which was made a few months ago.  You should be updating these tools all the time to get the latest versions of everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing 
 packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    } in Build.gradle(module:app) file above buildTypes{}tag

Comment: Hi ... I have made changes to the code. But still I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mentioned missing dependency too:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

Comment: Hi @breakline I have made changes to the code.But still i am getting this error.